# Proof that $\dfrac{1}{e^x}=e^{-x}$ without converting it to $e^{x}e^{-x}=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction, power-series, binomial-coefficients

I want to show that $\dfrac{1}{e^x} = e^{-x}$ from the Taylor expansion of $e^x$.

To express $\dfrac{1}{e^x}$ as a power series, I let:
$$
\left(\dfrac{1}{0!}x^0 + \dfrac{1}{1!}x^1 + \dfrac{1}{2!}x^2 + \dfrac{1}{3!}x^3 + \cdots \right) \left(b_0 x^0 + b_1 x^1 + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3 + \cdots \right) = 1x^0
$$

and start comparing coefficients from $x^0$ upwards. As expected, a pattern starts to emerge that $b_k = \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}$, but it gets quite messy quite quickly, so I'm not sure how I can formally prove that this pattern continues for all $k$.

I've thought about using induction, of course, but I can't come up with the correct way to set it up.

---

**Edit**: As @CameronWilliams correctly pointed out below, it would be easier to show that $e^{-x}e^{x}=1$, but I would *personally* find it more elegant to compute the reciprocal and then recognize that it happens to be $e^{-x}$.

Comment: I think a better way to go about it is to prove that $e^{-x}e^x = 1$ by writing out the power series of each and multiplying instead of trying to guess at the coefficients like this.. You **really** want to make use of Cauchy products for this.

Comment: @CameronWilliams True, it's just that I would pedagogically prefer to compute the reciprocal and then say "oh, that's the same function with a negative argument". I suspect that it would make for a better "aha moment" for a student, but I know this is subjective.

Comment: I get that, but I think it will make things a bit more challenging for yourself. Philosophically, the two approaches are similar but mine is a little bit more explicit.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Agreed, but unfortunately for myself, I'm a masochist. :)

Comment: TMI. Haha kidding. Well this way will teach you to be a lot more careful and methodical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}x^n\cdot\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}x^m = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$$

where

$$c_k = \sum_{n+m=k}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m!} = \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^{k}{k\choose n}(-1)^{n}$$

The last sum can be evaluated using the Binomial formula.

Comment: OP explicitly wants to avoid doing it this way.

Comment: This does exactly what I want to avoid (it shows that $e^x e^{-x} = 1$). I'm not going to down-vote it because it's not incorrect, but I can't accept it in this case.

Comment: @MGA Just divide both sides though by $e^x$.

Comment: @MGA Thats fine, I did not see your edit until now:)

Comment: @GammaFunction Ah, this is going to be confusing. It seems that it would have been better if I had just asked "calculate the $b$ coefficients in this equation" without the $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ context.

Comment: @MGA It should follow that $b_k = (-1)^k / k!$ for each $k$ pretty easily by induction.

Comment: @GammaFunction ... in which case you would perhaps have answered: "*conjecture* that $b_k = (-1)^k/k!$ and show that it's true." :)

Comment: @MGA Look at it this way: You know $e^x = \sum x^n/n!$. Now you try to find the inverse. You calculate a few terms and find that it looks like $b_n = (-1)^n/n!$. Now you conjectrue that the inverse is given exactly by this formula (you don't even have to know that this is the series for $e^{-x}$). The exercise above proves that your guess was correct. Then you might see that "my inverse its just the series for $e^{-x}$, wow!".

Comment: @Winther OK, you've worn me down :) I can kind of accept the argument "calculate the first few terms, make a conjecture from the pattern and show that it's true". Maybe that's the best way to work in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite what you're looking for, but it may be interesting to you and was too long to put in a comment. Rather than by an explicit series, it's also possible to define $y(x) = e^x$ as the unique solution (say, defined on the real line) of $y = y'$ with $y(0) = 1$. For any $a$, the function $y_a(x) = \frac{1}{y(a)}\, y(x + a)$ then also clearly satisfies $y_a'(x) = y_a(x)$ and $y_a(0) = 1$. Hence $y_a(x) = y(x)$; that is, $e^{x+a} = e^a e^x$ for fixed $a$. Taking $a = -x$ for some fixed $x$ gives the required result.

Comment: I was going to complain that "you only know that $e^{x-x} = 1$ because you've written it as an exponential", but then I realized that it had been defined that $y(0)=1$. OK, that's sexy.